# How many neurons are there in first layer of tensorflow model?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

Let's take example of standard MNIST example give on

```
www.tensorflow.com
```

Where there are `28*28` X parameters for a single image and `100,000` images.

Then how to determine number of neurons in first layer if I am usins simplistic neural network with no hidden layers.

Thanks.

PS: new to TF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input layer is the first layer, so this layer's size is 28 x 28 inputs, or 784, which corresponds to the 28 x 28 monochromatic pixels.

This concept is clearly shown in the [Tensorflow sample code for MNIST](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_deep.py). The blurb below shows that the input images' 28 x 28 pixels = 784 pixels define 784 as the value to be used as the size of the input. If there are `N_examples` sample images each of size 784, then the input tensor is `N_examples x 784`.

```
  Args:
    x: an input tensor with the dimensions (N_examples, 784), where 784 is the
    number of pixels in a standard MNIST image.
```

For more information on the nomenclature for the sizes, read the Stanford CS231n notes (particularly [these notes](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/) under the section "Layer-wise organization" and [these notes](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) on CNNs). Once you understand these concepts, everything will be clear.

Comment: I am not convinced, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @MayurBeldar: I added more details.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the number of hidden layers, the number of neurons in the input layer are the 28*28 = 724 neurons.  Tensor flow is going to train the network, taking the image and adjust the weights based on the calculated output and the actual output.  This can be done either sequentially (one at a time) or in a batch (using say 50 images and then updating).  for each run, the input layer is going to receive only 724 values of 0's and 1's

Answer (score 0):

the input layer has a dimension compatible with your input data, in this case you have images that are exactly 28x28 pixels.

Comment: So we can say there are 28*28 number of neurons?

Comment: @MayurBeldar in the first layer, yes.